# How to break down a string using CR LF characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an address string that I need to break down to 4 fields `Add1`, `Add2`…

I need to use `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` as the delimiter. The string looks like `text1CRLFtext2CRLFtext3`. I should have the following:

```
add1 = text1 (SUBSTRING(field, 0, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),field))
add2 = text2
add3 = text3
```

But I am having issues populating the remaining fields (how to calculate the length between the CRLFs).

This is on MS SQL server.

here is what I came up with

```
DECLARE @document VARCHAR(64);
SELECT @document = 'we
want
the
world
now';

SELECT addr1 = SUBSTRING(@document, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)-1)
SELECT addr2 = SUBSTRING(@document, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)-1-(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+1))
SELECT addr3 = SUBSTRING(@document, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2)-1-(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2-1))
SELECT addr4 = SUBSTRING(@document, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2)+2, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2)+2)-1-(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2)+2-1))
SELECT addr5 = SUBSTRING(@document, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2)+2)+2, LEN(@document)-CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@document)+2)+2)+2)-1)
```

Now I need to turn this into a view that handles four different scenarios – when the string has only one CRLF, when it has two or more CRLF, up to 4.

Comment: Will the address ***always*** have 4 lines? If not, could you describe how you want to lay out addresses with less than (or more than) 4 lines?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the formatting capabilities of Markdown offered when editing. Your code is extremely hard to read otherwise.

Comment: Anything beyond address 5 will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there will always be <= 4 lines, you can use this trick with `PARSENAME`:

```
DECLARE @add VARCHAR(4000) = 'My Name Is _____
123 4th St. W.
Newark, NJ
10104';

;WITH x(a) AS
(
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@add, '.', '$'),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'.')
)
SELECT add1 = REPLACE(PARSENAME(a,4),'$','.'), 
       add2 = REPLACE(PARSENAME(a,3),'$','.'), 
       add3 = REPLACE(PARSENAME(a,2),'$','.'), 
       add4 = REPLACE(PARSENAME(a,1),'$','.') 
FROM x;
```

This is a lot less messy when `.` can't naturally appear in the data, or when it is already the delimiter (e.g. IP address and four-part names).

Another way to do this is to create an ordered split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_Ordered]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Item 
    FROM (SELECT Number, Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO
```

Now you can say (given the same `@add` as given above):

```
SELECT a1 = [1], a2 = [2], a3 = [3], a4 = [4] 
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered(@add, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS s
PIVOT (MAX(Item) FOR [Index] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS p; 
GO
```

And if the information is in a table, no problem:

```
DECLARE @add TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), [address] VARCHAR(4000));

INSERT @add([address]) VALUES('My Name Is ______
221 3rd St.
Newark, NJ
10104'),
('Another name is...
345 Bruins Blvd.
Boston, MA
01251');

SELECT ID, a1 = [1], a2 = [2], a3 = [3], a4 = [4] 
FROM @add AS a
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered(a.[address], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS s
PIVOT (MAX(s.Item) FOR s.[Index] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS p; 
GO
```

Comment: The data is stored in a database table. so the ultimate goal is to create a view that breaks down the address string onto 4 fields using CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) to distinguish between each field

Comment: @user3087879 so you can create a view that uses the function. Or just create a stored procedure that uses the function (I don't know what benefit a view really adds).

Comment: Aaron, what is the best way to calculate the length between two delimiters example text1CRLFtext2CRLFtext3CRLFtext4. so how do we get the LEN for text2 and text3? thanks for your help again.

Comment: @user3087879 why do you need to calculate the length between the delimiters? You can do it here (e.g. `LEN([1])` on the last two queries) but I think you're missing the point of my solution - it already gives you the separate values so you don't need to measure the distance between delimiters

Comment: I am not sure how to use your code. I will need a view that treats 4 scenarios, when the string has one CRLF , when it has two up to 4. this view is to be used by end users to have a clean address format

Comment: @user3087879 I don't know how else I can help you - the description of your problem keeps changing and I don't know what you want to do when there are only 2 or 3 lines in the address - do you want to make assumptions about which lines are there? It sounds like you need a higher quality data cleansing solution than some T-SQL function is going to magically provide for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Declare @MyString varchar(200) = 'text1CRLFtext2CRLFtext3'
Declare @individual varchar(20) = null

WHILE LEN(@MyString) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%CRLF%',@MyString) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@MyString, 0, PATINDEX('%CRLF%',@MyString))
        SELECT @individual

        SET @MyString = SUBSTRING(@MyString, LEN(@individual + 'CRLF') + 1,
                                                     LEN(@MyString))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @MyString
        SET @MyString = NULL
        SELECT @individual
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we use PATINDEX to look for CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)? I just put CRLF in my example but I actually look for CHAR(13)CHAR(10)?

Comment: Looping sucks for one value. If you try to use this technique against a set it's going to be really bad.